# Datastax java driver session hangs

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

The following problem has occurred for the second time in few months. The session that tries to open and execute the query using the java driver hangs the particular thread. As a result of this , this particular thread waits forever and causes a thread locking problem. This was resolved using an app server restart . But , one cannot manually intervene for these kind of driver problems . Does anyone have an idea on this?

> sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:747)
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:905)
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1217)
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:292)
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
>   com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(ResultSetFuture.java:181)
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Session.execute(Session.java:111)
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Session.execute(Session.java:80)

Comment: You'll probably find more help at https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/java-driver-user

Answer (score 0):

There is an open ticket on this issue (https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-268). Your best bet would be adding any information you have to that ticket.